# I don't understand how positive look-ahead ( ?= ) works

Tags: python, regex

I am going to show you how I believe the regular expression works on a concrete program, which you've probably seen before on here :

```
# strongPassword.py

# Strong Password Detection
# Write a function that uses regular expressions to make sure
# the password string it is passed is strong. A strong password
# is defined as one that is at least eight characters long,
# contains both uppercase and lowercase characters, and has
# at least one digit. You may need to test the string against
# multiple regex patterns to validate its strength.

import pyperclip, re

passwordRegex = re.compile(r'''(
    ^(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])                # at least two capital letters
    (?=.*[!@#$&*])                     # at least one of these special characters
    (?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])                 # at least two numeric digits
    (?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z])          # at least three lower case letters
    .{10,}                              # at least 10 total digits
    $
    )''', re.VERBOSE)

def userInputPasswordCheck():
    ppass = input("Enter a potential password: ")
    mo = passwordRegex.search(ppass)
    if (not mo):
        print("Not strong, bling blong")
        return False
    else:
        print("Long, Strong, and down to get the crypto on")
        return True


userInputPasswordCheck()
```

Let's say the given string is `'Azb@Ag2!H3'`.

Match the first part of the string if its followed by two capital letters either at the place of first two characters in the string or anywhere inbetween it ( because of the `.*` ). Since it matches only what's before this part of regex, the string matches nothing here but whatever. The thing I mentioned previously will be matches if it is followed by any number of characters ( including zero ) after which comes one of the following characters : `!@#$&*`. This basically means that, since the at symbol is placed after the first and before the last required capital letters from the first part of the regex, *it will not even count* and, unless another symbol among those mentioned above appears after the two capital letters, *the string will not match*. This is not what the program is supposed to do ; it should match the string if it has one symbol anywhere around it ; not just after a specific character or number of characters, am I right ?

There's no need to continue analyzing how the program goes because you see the pattern. This is the problem for every other part of the regular expression I haven't mentioned.

**The question is:** Am I getting something wrong here ? I read multiple sources, on stack overflow and other sites, to no avail. I still struggle and feel like I'm not understanding how the code works inherently.

Maybe the program has to be completed in another way which I'm not aware of.

---

**Follow-up Question:** how do I modify this code ( the regex object in particular ), so it matches not the minimum 10-character-long string satisfying all the requirements given in the code within itself, but a string which is *prededed* by those requirements ( at least two capital letters, three non-capital letters, two numeric digits and one special character ), returning only the 10+ number of characters after, if all the requirements have been satisfied, while ignoring the lookahead-assertions when returning the string.

Comment: `?=` is a (positive) lookahead, i.e. it basically says "starting from the start of the string `^`, check if the rest of the string has two capital letters (first `(?=...)`), _then go back_ and check if the rest of the string matches, this, and this, and this (other lookaheads)

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: *"Since it matches only what's before this part of regex, the string matches nothing here but whatever."* – are you confusing this with lookbehind? That's what lookbehind would do, but this is lookahead which matches what's *after* this part.

Comment: Wait, did you just completely modify the question to mean something entirely different? Don't do that! Rolling back to the old version. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: They banned me and according to the message I received the bans on here last forever, unless you improve the existing questions by editing them and get better reputation through those modified questions. I just got an extra downvote though, so I guess it doesn't help...

Comment: You did not get an extra downvote but I removed my own upvote (for now) after the invalid edit. Sorry about that, but completely changing the question is _not_ improving the question. If you have a follow-up question, you may also _add_ this to the question **without** removing the original question and thus invalidating all existing answers. I may try to help you with this, too, but now it's late.

Comment: I'd immensely appreciate your help if you are willing.

Comment: Does that mean that the original question is now answered, you understand how those lookaheads work, and now you want to know how the regex would have to look to behave like (I assume) you originaly though it would behave? And if so, do you actually have a use for this, or is this purely out of interest?

Comment: Yes it's true. I guess I do get what you were saying now, I was just sluggish in contemplating the problem.
The reason I want the other question answered is because it feels like the only way to fully understand the previous problem. I get it now, but I don't get how I could do the other thing which I previously thought the code above was doing all this time.

Answer (score 2):

> This basically means that, since the at symbol is placed after the first and before the last required capital letters from the first part of the regex, IT WILL NOT EVEN COUNT

From your description, you seem to understand the regex as "look for two capital letters, and then look for a special character *after those*, and so on". But this is not the case here.

The parts with `?=` are called "positive lookaheads" and they check whether the enclosed pattern matches (a prefix of) the string starting from the current position (the start of the string `^` in this case), *without actually advancing the position in the string*. In other words:

- `^`: Start of the string
- `(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])`: Check remainder for two capital letters, *then back to start*<sup>1)</sup>
- `(?=.*[!@#$&*])`: Check remainder for special character, *then back to start*
- `(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])`: Check remainder for digit, *then back to start*
- `(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z])`: Check remainder for three lowercase letters, *back to start*
- `.{10,}`: Any ten or more characters (and this time not back to start)
- `$`: End of string

Considering your example `'Azb@Ag2!H3'`, or `^Azb@Ag2!H3$` with added `^` and `$`. The "cursor" of the regex-matcher starts at `^` and immediately starts the first lookahead, matching it with the prefix `Azb@A`, but because it is a lookahead, the cursor does not end at the 2nd `A` but goes back to `^`. Next it matches the prefix `Azb@` and goes back to `^`, then `Azb@Ag2!H3` and `Azb@Ag`. Now the cursor is back at the `^` for the 6th time and finally matches `.{10,}` with `Azb@Ag2!H3`. *Now* the cursor is at the `$` and the matching is completed.

If this does not clear it up, maybe [this documentation / tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with more examples helps.

You can also paste your Regex and example string in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/SXzpaM/1) or similar pages, read the regex-specific explanation that is generated there, and experiment with changing parts of the expression.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Actually "back to the position before the lookahead", which in this case is the start `^`

Comment: Doesn't the whole bracket mean 'match a string if it's preceded by this' ? I don't really understand, if it truly goes back to the start after each positive lookahead, which string comes after each lookahead ? Ten+ characters ( .{10,} ) ? But then, the string never will have 10 characters right ? Because before 10 characters, there will always have to be some characters ( wether it be capital letters, small letters, numbers or special symbols ) depending on the parentheses. How does that work ?

Comment: @WilliamFrog8 I don't quite understand. It goes back to the position where it started the lookahead (`^` in this case) each time, so after the last lookahead, it is back at the start and finally matches the remainder with ten or more characters.

Comment: Check .{10,} if it is preceded by at least 2 capital letters, at least one special symbol, at least 2 digits, at least three non-capital letters. This means that the whole string has to be at least 8 characters long. How come this code correctly matches a string with at least 10 characters ?

Comment: @WilliamFrog8 Because (a) what I am trying to tell you is the `.{10,}` does not have to be preceded by all those characters, because the matching goes _back to the start_ after each lookahead, and (b) 10 is more than 8?

Comment: But 10 characters of ANY KIND are in front of all these requirements, do you get what I'm saying ? I'm literally crying because of how frustrating this problem that I can't wrap my head around is. I'm sorry, but thank you anyway, you tried to help...

Comment: @WilliamFrog8 Sorry, no, I truly do not get what you are saying. Why do you think that "10 chars ... are in front of all there req."? The `.{10,}` part is checked last, after all those zero-width lookaheads.

Comment: How can it be checked last if the whole point of lookadhead assertions is that they match the string if it's preceded by a particular substring without returning the given substring ? Even if chained lookahead assertions don't interact with each other, but with the next part of the regex that isn't a lookahead assertion ( in this case 10+ whatever-characters ), the 10+ characters will be matched and returned only if they're PRECEDED BY all those required characters.

Comment: Not if THEY ARE those characters. It doesn't matter whether THEY ARE those characters as well, but they have to be preceded by them. So, the whole string has to be at least 18 characters long ( required 8 characters at the beginning of different types + minimum of 10 characters following ). Do you get what I am saying now ?

Comment: @WilliamFrog8 Please read my answer again, very carefully. And then maybe another time, just for good measure. The whole point of the look_ahead_ is that the following parts do _not_ have to be preceded by the stuff in the lookahead, but the "cursor" position in the string is reset to _before_ the lookahead. I really don't know how else to explain it.

Comment: But is each look-ahead counted to be followed by the .{10,} ? That means that there has to be at least 2 characters ( if we look at the first look-ahead ) preceding the 10+ characters...

Comment: I read every single comment of yours multiple times, and even the link you submitted ( the whole webpage ) twice, apparently to no avail.

Comment: @WilliamFrog8 No, why should each lookahead be followed by the `.{10,}` part? The first look_ahead_ _zero-width_ assertion looks **ahead** of the current position `^` while advancing the cursor **zero** positions, then the second look-ahead does the same, and when you are at the `.{10,}` you looked **ahead** 5 times and advanced **zero** width each time, still being on the `^`.

Comment: So, if I wanted to match a string of 10+ characters preceded by the required characters ( so basically the minimum of 18 characters in total ), how could I do that ?